# Django: Error with django content type

Tags: django

I got error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: insert or update on table "auth_permission" violates foreign key constraint "auth_content_type_id_508cf46651277a81_fk_django_content_type_id"
 DETAIL:  Key (content_type_id)=(1) is not present in table "django_content_type".
```

I found [this post](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10827) but no recommendation helps:

```
ContentType.objects.clear_cache()

move 'django.contrib.contenttypes' before 'django.contrib.auth' in INSTALLED_APPS
```

Has anyone found a solution to this problem?

For details: my settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.postgres',
    'webpack_loader',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'common',
    'humans',
    'validations',
    'accounts',
    'comments',
    'errors',  
    'django_nose',
    'reports',
    'dashboards',
    'cacheops',
    'djcelery',
)
```

Comment: can you just share the settings file code?

Comment: @amankumar INSTALLED_APPS ?

Comment: yes. INSTALLED_APPS. Most probably error is due to db setup at migrate time.

Comment: @amankumar please see on new details. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSTALLED_APPS=(
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
     .....
     .....
)
```

can you change the order. reset the db run migrate again.

Comment: this is nothing to do with op's question